# Clustering communication patterns to detect multiple identities

Tags: clustering, feature-selection, similarities, spatio-temporal

I have a data set of communication patterns between chatting agents. 
Each agent can have multiple profiles or identities. 
I am interested in developing a way to investigate the similarity between 
various profiles. The problem is that there is no real indicator whether two 
profiles belong to the same agent.

The set of features describes the frequency of messages through the hours of the 
day, days of the week, months, and years.

The aim is to learn the significant features that indicate similar profiles 
that belong to one agent.

The proposed approach: considering each data item to be the communication pattern 
of one agent over a year. This way, the data set would have many data items that 
represent the communication patterns of the same agent across different years. 
We apply clustering with a number of clusters equal to the number of agents--not 
profiles. Ideally, if the clustering algorithm clusters the data points that belong to one agent in one cluster then we have a features model that we could 
use to detect profiles of the same agent.

Of course this proposal assumes that the agent would have the same pattern in 
the different profiles, which is not expected to be the case. But among the data 
set of the all agents, this way may give a correct prediction with a certain 
level of accuracy.

Does this approach sound reasonable? 
Is there a better way to tackle this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: The hard part is determining what constitutes a "communication pattern" and how to evaluate how similar two such patterns are.  What do you propose for this?  (Your discussion of "features," "patterns," "data items," and "similar" is too vague to evaluate.)

Comment: - communication pattern refers to frequency of messages disclosed by an agent over the different periods
- the similarity in that case would be the measure of similar message disclosure frequencies